# I am getting NullPointerException from spring service

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am trying to build a basic webpage with `Spring` + `JSF`.
Basically, I have one  `HelloController` and `HelloSpringService`.
It gives error on the return `helloSpringService.sayHello();` line in `HelloController` class.

```
public class HelloController {


    @ManagedProperty("#{helloSpringService)")
    private HelloSpringService helloSpringService;

    public String showHello() {

        return helloSpringService.sayHello();
    }

    public void setHelloSpringService(HelloSpringService helloSpringService) {
        this.helloSpringService = helloSpringService;
    }
    public HelloSpringService getHelloSpringService() {
        return helloSpringService;
    }

}
```

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HelloSpringService {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "hellofromspringservice";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the answer in the SO post that I commented above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Autowired` instead of `@ManagedProperty("#{helloSpringService)")`

Comment: Not fully right...See the duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

You have created the bean HelloSpringService as a service bean so Spring core is responsible for the life cycle of the bean so you must call it with @Autowired instead of @ManagedProperty.

Comment: Not fully right...See the duplicate...

Answer (score -1):

```
helloSpringService
```

should be *autowired* rather than included as *managedproperty*

Comment: How does this differ (and is significantly better) than the other answers?

Comment: This comment was added almost the same time the other ones were added, when i posted this, I did't see the other comments. Could be due to the fact that i was on the page for a longer time, and didn't reload the page before publishing my comment